# Changing desktop environment on Pop!_OS

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia, desktop-environment

If I change my desktop environment, will that affect my Xorg server settings? For example, my Xorg server is configured to run on my dedicated GPU (Nvidia Optimus). Will that change? If so, how do I prevent that? I'm currently running Pop!_OS 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I wouldn't think so.

**You're installing a desktop environment, which is essentially a graphical interface with some applications. The DE will have configurations of its own, but it shouldn't mess with your Xorg Server configurations.**

If anyone disagrees, I'd like to hear about it. I'm confident that everything should be okay though.

Thanks for asking! If the answer helps, I'd like you to mark my answer as helpful

Comment: Ik this is unrelated to my problem but could u please guide me through it.

Comment: Guide you through the installation of one? I'd recommend looking on YouTube for that. They'll be much more useful than I am at guiding you through installing a desktop environment.

Comment: But, it generally just goes like this: 1. you install the DE 2: Logout (or shutdown and turn on again or reboot) and you will find the DE in your login screen with your default DE. I'm looking at an image of a pop OS screen, and it looks like there should be a cog just next to 'Sign in'. If you click it, it will show your desktop environments which are installed.

Comment: thanks! Ill check out youtube.